# Tagged photos posted in closed group

Tags: facebook

I was tagged in a photo in a closed group. Can my friends that are not in that group see the tagged photo?

Answer (score 1):

People that are not in a closed group can't see posts inside it. Posts include photos.

[image]

---

So, your friends won't see that you have been tagged in a closed group photo.